# Best way to flatten an object with array properties into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js, lodash

Imagine I have

```
const obj = {
  arr_a: [9, 3, 2],
  arr_b: [1, 5, 0],
  arr_c: [7, 18]
}
```

what's the best way to convert this object to a simple array like:

```
[9, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0, 7, 18]
```

I tried this:

```
[].concat(obj.arr_a, obj.arr_b, obj.arr_c)
```

But I wonder if there's something in `lodash` or `underscore` to do it. Something like:

```
_.flatAsArray(obj);
```

or:

```
obj.toFlatArray();
```

Comment: Is it just arr_a,b,c or n properties you are looking for ?

Comment: Are there always 3 known properties?

Comment: In this case yes but I'd prefer to know a more dynamic way

Answer (score 1):

To get the values of all keys in object, you can use `_.values`.

With ES6

```
[].concat(..._.values(obj))
```

With `_.flatten`

```
_.flatten(_.values(obj))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap) to get all these values.

```
var result = _.flatMap(obj);
```

```js
const obj = {
  arr_a: [9, 3, 2],
  arr_b: [1, 5, 0],
  arr_c: [7, 18]
};

var result = _.flatMap(obj);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
_.flatten(_.values(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var obj = { arr_a: [9, 3, 2], arr_b: [1, 5, 0], arr_c: [7, 18] },
    result = Object.values(obj).reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to iterate over the object values, [reducing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) them using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```
Object.values(obj).reduce((result, val) => [...result, ...val], [])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Adam thanks for the feedback, I've edited my answer